# Why can't I adjust the brightness levels of a PNG file

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I have some scanned images which vary in brightness. I desire to equalize the brightness levels to make the images (as a group) more consistent. I borrowed some code from SO (with minor changes) that was described as doing what I needed. But the code seems to have no effect at all. Obviously I’m doing something wrong but I can’t seem to figure it out. What I am trying to do is read the perceived brightness level of the original images and from that calculate a target brightness level and pass that value to a function that will (theoretically) alter the image brightness to the perceived brightness level and create a new image file.

```
from os import listdir
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageStat
import operator
import math

def brightness(fname):
    with Image.open(fname) as img:
        stat = ImageStat.Stat(img)
        r,g,b = stat.mean

    return int(math.sqrt(0.241*(r**2) + 0.691*(g**2) + 0.068*(b**2)))


def change_brightness(fname, value):
    if value == 0: return
    img = cv2.imread(SourceDir+fname,)
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    cv2.add(hsv[:,:,2], value, hsv[:,:,2])

    img = cv2.cvtColor(hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    cv2.imwrite(DestDir+fname, img)


SourceDir = 'I:\\'
DestDir = 'G:\\Documents\\'
InputFiles = []
BrightnessLevels = {}
TargetBrightness = 130

InputFiles = listdir(SourceDir)
try:
    InputFiles.remove('System Volume Information')
except:
    pass

InputFiles.sort()

for InputFile in InputFiles:
    old_b = brightness(SourceDir+InputFile)
    change = TargetBrightness-old_b
    change_brightness(InputFile, change)
    new_b = brightness(DestDir+InputFile)
    BrightnessLevels[InputFile] = (old_b, change, new_b)

sorted_b = sorted(BrightnessLevels.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
for f,b in sorted_b:
    print(f,b)
```

The results I get is as follows:

```
Page-003.png (89, 41, 89)
Page-082.png (89, 41, 89)
Page-047.png (90, 40, 89)
Page-075.png (92, 38, 91)
Page-111.png (92, 38, 91)
Page-071.png (92, 38, 92)
Page-074.png (92, 38, 92)
Page-077.png (92, 38, 92)
Page-112.png (93, 37, 93)
Page-079.png (94, 36, 93)
Page-078.png (94, 36, 94)
Page-031.png (95, 35, 95)
Page-083.png (95, 35, 95)
Page-023.png (96, 34, 96)
Page-050.png (96, 34, 96)
Page-081.png (96, 34, 96)
Page-098.png (96, 34, 96)
Page-099.png (96, 34, 96)
Page-033.png (97, 33, 96)
Page-094.png (97, 33, 97)
Page-107.png (97, 33, 97)
Page-038.png (98, 32, 98)
Page-039.png (98, 32, 98)
Page-095.png (98, 32, 98)
Page-096.png (98, 32, 98)
Page-106.png (98, 32, 98)
Page-108.png (98, 32, 98)
Page-018.png (99, 31, 99)
Page-046.png (99, 31, 99)
Page-072.png (99, 31, 99)
Page-097.png (99, 31, 99)
Page-066.png (100, 30, 99)
Page-080.png (100, 30, 99)
Page-110.png (100, 30, 99)
Page-011.png (100, 30, 100)
Page-121.png (100, 30, 100)
Page-109.png (101, 29, 100)
Page-006.png (101, 29, 101)
Page-051.png (101, 29, 101)
Page-007.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-010.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-015.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-025.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-049.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-052.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-056.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-065.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-076.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-086.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-102.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-122.png (102, 28, 102)
Page-067.png (103, 27, 102)
Page-092.png (103, 27, 102)
Page-116.png (103, 27, 102)
Page-014.png (103, 27, 103)
Page-084.png (103, 27, 103)
Page-103.png (103, 27, 103)
Page-115.png (103, 27, 103)
Page-026.png (104, 26, 103)
Page-059.png (104, 26, 103)
Page-012.png (104, 26, 104)
Page-024.png (104, 26, 104)
Page-048.png (104, 26, 104)
Page-123.png (104, 26, 104)
Page-009.png (105, 25, 105)
Page-034.png (105, 25, 105)
Page-087.png (105, 25, 105)
Page-114.png (105, 25, 105)
Page-118.png (105, 25, 105)
Page-119.png (105, 25, 105)
Page-030.png (106, 24, 105)
Page-043.png (106, 24, 105)
Page-062.png (106, 24, 105)
Page-063.png (106, 24, 105)
Page-035.png (106, 24, 106)
Page-126.png (106, 24, 106)
Page-113.png (107, 23, 106)
Page-044.png (107, 23, 107)
Page-068.png (107, 23, 107)
Page-019.png (108, 22, 107)
Page-070.png (108, 22, 107)
Page-054.png (108, 22, 108)
Page-064.png (108, 22, 108)
Page-090.png (108, 22, 108)
Page-002.png (109, 21, 108)
Page-058.png (109, 21, 108)
Page-091.png (109, 21, 108)
Page-020.png (109, 21, 109)
Page-101.png (109, 21, 109)
Page-104.png (110, 20, 109)
Page-032.png (110, 20, 110)
Page-004.png (111, 19, 111)
Page-040.png (112, 18, 111)
Page-021.png (112, 18, 112)
Page-041.png (112, 18, 112)
Page-061.png (113, 17, 113)
Page-016.png (114, 16, 114)
Page-055.png (114, 16, 114)
Page-008.png (115, 15, 114)
Page-117.png (115, 15, 115)
Page-042.png (116, 14, 116)
Page-036.png (118, 12, 117)
Page-085.png (130, 0, 129)
Page-022.png (131, -1, 131)
Page-073.png (131, -1, 131)
Page-027.png (133, -3, 132)
Page-124.png (133, -3, 132)
Page-005.png (133, -3, 133)
Page-057.png (134, -4, 133)
Page-013.png (135, -5, 135)
Page-037.png (135, -5, 135)
Page-105.png (137, -7, 137)
Page-120.png (137, -7, 137)
Page-045.png (138, -8, 138)
Page-060.png (139, -9, 139)
Page-093.png (139, -9, 139)
Page-017.png (140, -10, 140)
Page-125.png (141, -11, 140)
Page-089.png (142, -12, 141)
Page-029.png (142, -12, 142)
Page-028.png (143, -13, 142)
Page-069.png (145, -15, 145)
Page-053.png (147, -17, 146)
Page-100.png (149, -19, 149)
Page-088.png (150, -20, 149)
```

The first value of the tuple is the initial perceived brightness of the image. The second value is the calculated adjustment to the brightness level. The third value is the perceived brightness level of the new image file. No matter what adjustment values I try, they don't seem to have any effect. And by visually looking at the files seem to agree that they look the same as the originals.

Comment: Why are you mixing up PIL/Pillow i.e `Image.open(fname)` with OpenCV for everything else? You are going to confuse yourself, just open the images with OpenCV `imread()`

Comment: `brightness` and `change_brightness` use a different definition of "brightness". Make `brightness` return the mean of `hsv[:,:,2]` for a more meaningful result.

Comment: It would be most helpful to see your input and output images.

Comment: The images are of a personal nature. Family genealogy and pictures and stuff. I would have to come up with something else. Would you prefer I do that?

Comment: I presumed that hsv was a well defined image data format. I was just using python to read and write that data format. It did not occur to me that different library functions would have their own unique definitions of the hsv format. Correct me if I'm wrong on this?

Comment: The reason I suggested to stick to OpenCV, rather than mixing things is that it can trip you up if you are unaware of the differences between the packages. For example OpenCV stores images in BGR order rather than RGB so you will get your Reds and Blues swapped if you switch between libraries without taking account of that. Likewise, OpenCV converts palette images to RGB on load, whereas PIL gives you the palette indices. `skimage` for example expects pixels  in the range 0..1, whereas OpenCV and PIL tend to use a range of 0..255. It's ok to switch between libraries, but you need to watch out.

Comment: Good advice. Thanks, Mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line:

```
cv2.add(hsv[:,:,2], value, hsv[:,:,2])
```

so it looks like this:

```
hsv[:,:,2] = cv2.add(hsv[:,:,2], value)
```

It doesn't work how the documentation implies - I don't know why.

Comment: Hey, that worked. It appears I was misled by my source. Thanks Mark. Tag this one as solved.